# Health Check on Fabric CA

Tags: hyperledger-fabric-ca

I have a `hyperledger` fabric network v2.2.0 deployed with 2 peer orgs and an orderer org in a `kubernetes` cluster. Each org has its own CA server. The CA pod keeps on restarting sometimes. In order to know whether the service of the CA server is reachable or not, I am trying to use the `healthz` API on port 9443.

I have used the [`livenessProbe`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-a-liveness-http-request) condition in the CA deployment like so:

```
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      httpGet:
        path: /healthz
        port: 9443
        scheme: HTTP
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 1
```

After configuring this liveness probe, the pod keeps on restarting with the event `Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with status code: 400`. Why might this be happening?

Comment: What response do you get if you send a GET request directly to the `hyperledger` `/healthz` resource yourself? What is the output of `kubectl describe pod liveness-request`?

Answer (score 2):

[HTTP 400 code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400):

> The HTTP 400 Bad Request response status code indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (for example, malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

This indicates that Kubernetes is sending the data in a way `hyperledger` is rejecting, but without more information it is hard to say where the problem is. Some quick checks to start with:

- Send some GET requests directly to the `hyperledger` `/healthz` resource yourself. What do you get? You should get back either a `200 "OK"` if everything is functioning, or a `503 "Service Unavailable"` with details of which nodes are down ([docs](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/operations_service.html#health-checks)).
- `kubectl describe pod liveness-request`. You should see a few lines towards the bottom describing the state of the liveness probe in more detail:

```
Restart Count:  0
.
.
.
Events:
Type Reason Age From Message
---- ------ ---- ---- -------
Normal Scheduled <unknown> default-scheduler Successfully assigned example-dc/liveness-request to dcpoz-d-sou-k8swor3
Normal Pulling 4m45s kubelet, dcpoz-d-sou-k8swor3 Pulling image "nginx"
Normal Pulled 4m42s kubelet, dcpoz-d-sou-k8swor3 Successfully pulled image "nginx"
Normal Created 4m42s kubelet, dcpoz-d-sou-k8swor3 Created container liveness
Normal Started 4m42s kubelet, dcpoz-d-sou-k8swor3 Started container liveness
```

Some other things to investigate:

- `httpGet` options that might be helpful:

  - scheme – Protocol type HTTP or HTTPS
  - httpHeaders– Custom headers to set in the request
  - Have you [configured the operations service](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/operations_service.html#configuring-the-operations-service)?
- You may need a valid client certificate (if TLS is enabled, and `clientAuthRequired` is set to `true`).